# Is thera an Autocad export file so it is programmatically readable?

Tags: autocad

I would like to extract the coordinates (latitude, longitude) and some properties like name and colour of Autocad files. I may do this from a Java program.

From Autocad, which is the right format to export to so I can programmatically parse the file, look for objects and get their properties? (coordinates, name, colour...)

I know Autocad DWG format is a propietary binary file that changes its format every 3 years, so I need to find a file format to export to that allow me to read it easily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DXF is what you're looking for. It's a documented format for drawing exchange in plain text.

http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/acad_dxf0.pdf

Comment: What about a library in php or java that parses a DXF file? Any experience on that?

Comment: Not sure what that link used to point to, but does not go to any DXF related information.

Answer (score 0):

DXF is definitely the best format if you're not using a vertical product like Civil or Map.  Some vertical products can also export SHP/SHX (shape) files.

Here's references for DXF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD_DXF, http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/acad_dxf0.pdf

Here's a SHP reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile